# finding the left substring is equal to right substring

Tags: substring

Write a function which given a string S returns the index (counting from 0) of character such that the substring on its left is a reversed susbstring on its right (or -1 if such an index does not exist).

For example, given a string

racecar

Function should return 3, because the substring on the left of the character e at index 3 is rac, and the one on the right is car.

Comment: Firstly, you haven't said what language you're using. Secondly, it sounds a lot like homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework

Comment: I will do no such thing. Please rephrase your request in terms of a question, instead of as an order. The text is obviously a homework/exam type of question, and while those are welcome here, they are only welcome when you a) narrow down what part you're having problems with, and b) tell us what you tried and how that went.

Answer (score 1):

get the length/2 and verify lengths first and then if the lengths are same then reverse the first half and compare with the second.

Comment: can u give me the program in any language

Answer (score 1):

Example function:

```
    private int TestMethod1(string str)
    {
        if (str.Length > 0)
        {
            if (str.Length % 2 != 0)
            {
                string strFront = string.Empty;
                for (int i = (str.Length / 2) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    strFront += str.Substring(i, 1);
                }

                if (strFront.Equals(str.Substring((str.Length / 2) + 1)))
                {
                    return str.Length / 2;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```